# Sequence of actions with redux-observable

Tags: redux, redux-saga, side-effects, redux-observable

Here's the flow I want to implement: the list of all users is publicly available on my backend API, so I wish to see if the user already exists, if no, create a new user.

I'm using Redux, and I'm managing side effects with redux-observable. Here's the flow, with the relevant actions I'm sending.

- Button click dispatches the action `FIND_OR_CREATE_USER`. Side effect should handle the next steps.
- Find user in the API backend - dispatch `GET_USER_BY_ID_REQUEST` with a userId param, side-effect will do the HTTP call.
- Receive user - dispatch `GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS`, the response is stored in the state.
- If this response is empty, then create a user with `CREATE_USER_REQUEST`.

Now the only thing is that this `GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS` is also used somewhere else in the app (e.g. to get a user profile). So I cannot listen to `GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS` and create a user right after it if the response is empty. Only create a user if we have a `GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS` which follows a `FIND_OR_CREATE_USER`.

Here's how I would do it with redux-sagas:

```
function* findOrCreateUserSaga() {
  yield put({ type: 'GET_USER_BY_ID_REQUEST', payload: userId });
  yield take('GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS');
  const response = yield select((state) => state.user);
  if (!response) {
    yield put({ type: 'CREATE_USER' }, payload: someObject );
  }
}

...

yield takeLatest('FIND_OR_CREATE_USER', findOrCreateUserSaga)
```

How can I implement the same flow in a reactive way, with redux-observable?

Answer (score 2):

You can create new subscriptions to the `action$` stream at any point in time in an epic. This allows you to dynamically start/stop listening for specific actions in response to other actions, workflows, etc..

Here's the example saga translated to RxJS 6 (using pipes) and redux-observable 1+ (using the `state$` stream). It uses the `merge` function to create an observable that both emits the "GET_USER_BY_ID_REQUEST" and listens for "GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS". Additionally, the `first` operator used within the inner `action$` stream pipe causes it to complete when your matching action occurs.

```js
const epic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType('FIND_OR_CREATE_USER'),
  switchMap(action =>
    merge(
      of({ type: 'GET_USER_BY_ID_REQUEST', payload: userId }),
      action$.pipe(
        ofType('GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS'),
        first(),
        withLatestFrom(state$),
        mergeMap(([action, state]) =>
          state.user
            ? empty()
            : of({ type: 'CREATE_USER', payload: someObject })
        ),
      ),
    )
  ),
)
```

The example saga didn't specify how the `userId` and `someObject` variables are created. Note that the same is true of the above example epic. However, it should be easy enough to fill in these gaps based on your specific use case.